# HIVE:how to calculate seconds difference of time format: yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss

Tags: time, hive, timestamp, hiveql, datetime-format

How to calculate seconds difference of time format:`yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss`?
For example,calculate seconds difference of `20190102 00:01:05` and `20190102 02:14:18`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) function to convert timestamps to seconds, then subtract:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('20190102 02:14:18','yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss') -
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP('20190102 00:01:05','yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss');
```

Returns:

`7993` seconds.

Difference in `'HH:mm:ss'` format:

```
select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('20190102 02:14:18','yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss') -
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP('20190102 00:01:05','yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss'), 'HH:mm:ss');
```

Returns:

```
02:13:13
```

Also you can use solution how to format seconds in `'HH:mm:ss'` using explicit math proposed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57497316/2700344