# Hive/SQL Error when converting milliseconds to DDDD:HH:mm:ss

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql, unix-timestamp

I have an output in milliseconds that is too big to be described in HH:mm:ss format, I will need to expand to DDDD:HH:mm:ss.

The code I'm currently using only works on big numbers:

```
select from_unixtime(cast(floor(2513702864/1000) as bigint), 'DDDD:HH:mm:ss');
```

gives:  0030:02:15:02 , this is correct

```
select from_unixtime(cast(floor(17259/1000) as bigint), 'DDDD:HH:mm:ss');
```

gives: 0001:00:00:17 , this is not correct.

```
select from_unixtime(cast(floor(127259/1000) as bigint), 'DDDD:HH:mm:ss');
```

gives: 0001:00:02:07, this is also not correct.

How to fix the erroneous 1 in DDDD part when dealing with smaller milliseconds?

Comment: Please explain initial task. It is not clear what are you doing. What DDDD means, why four D??? year has 365 days... and it is always some day: today, yesterday, tomorrow, if you have D in your pattern it will be some day in a year, not zero. because function returns timestamp formatted

Comment: I simply just want to display the milliseconds in number of days + hrs + mms + seconds. Now when you explained by a day in a year, it is making sense now because the 1 is just a day in the year, but I was just trying to convert milliseconds into days without define it as 1 day in the year. Days can go above 365 days if it is over a decade. Is there a way to just convert to days without having it in reference to a year?

Comment: @leftjoin do you think there is a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is simple math. BIGINT timestamp is the number of seconds or milliseconds passed from Unix Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).

To get milliseconds part use `(ts % 1000)` - returns reminder after division by 1000

To get total whole seconds passed, use `(ts div 1000)` - returns integer part, all other figures will be calculated from this number: days, hours, minutes, seconds.

days: `(ts div 1000) div 86400` - returns integer part after division of total seconds by number of seconds in a day

To get hours left after whole days calculation: take reminder after days calculation  `((ts div 1000) % 86400)` and divide by number of seconds in hour, take integer part `(((ts div 1000) % 86400) div 3600)`

And so on.

Demo:

```
with your_data as (
select 1 id, bigint(2513702864) ts union all
select 2, bigint(17259) union all
select 3,bigint(127259) union all
select 4,bigint(1272) union all
select 5,bigint(127)
)

select --format output as required. For example days:hours:minutes:seconds.millis
       concat(days,':',hours,':',minutes,':',seconds,'.',millis)
from
(
select ((ts div 1000) div 86400) days, --number of whole days
       lpad(((ts div 1000) % 86400) div 3600, 2, 0) hours, --whole hours left
       lpad((((ts div 1000) % 86400) % 3600) div 60, 2, 0) minutes, --whole minutes left
       lpad((((ts div 1000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60, 2, 0) seconds, --seconds left
       (ts % 1000) as millis
  from your_data
)s
```

Result:

```
1 29:02:15:02.864 --29 whole days, 2 hours, 15 minutes, 2 seconds, 864 millis
2 0:00:00:17.259 --17 whole seconds and 259 millis
3 0:00:02:07.259 --two whole minutes, 7 seconds and 259 millis
4 0:00:00:01.272 --one whole second and millis
5 0:00:00:00.127 --we have only milliseconds
```

Now you can see the difference between this calculation and what from_unixtime returns.
For record id=1 the number of whole days is 29. Why from_unixtime returns 30 (for [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) 'D')? Because 29 whole days passed and we are 2 hrs 15 min 2 sec 864 mi in a new day 30. In other words, from_unixtime returns timestamp formatted and calculation in my query returns interval formatted, "day in a year" and "whole days passed from" are different things.

Hope, now it is as clear as a day.

See also similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57497316/2700344

And if you need to convert bigint timestamp in milliseconds to string with milliseconds preserved (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`) use this:

```
select concat(from_unixtime(ts div 1000), '.', (ts  % 1000)) as timestamp_with_millis
  from (select bigint(2513702864)  as ts) s
```

Result:

```
1970-01-30 02:15:02.864
```

Comment: You are the best!